# Can not access to Hard Drive in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, chkdsk

I have a old laptop HDD, which i have plugged into my laptop using a HDD Adapter via USB. Now the Hard disk is visible on computer management in windows 7 but not in the explorer.
[image]
Now from the DISPART i guess that the E: drive is this HDD.
[image]
Am I doing it right?
If so then chkdsk should work?
[image]
 But chkdsk failed :/ so what i should do to restore the data of this hard disk? 
Many Thanks :)

Comment: You need to right click on the drive and create a new volume? It looks like unallocated space at the moment. For example on your other drive you can see the letters and the volume size, do the same?

Comment: Ow no, i have 150GB data on it :/

Comment: Right click and change letter and paths?

Comment: I can't find any option there! http://i.stack.imgur.com/M2Uhv.png

Comment: It's right there... Change drive letter and paths... 4th option down on the right click menu.

Comment: its not working shows an error

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Here is the error msg: http://i.imgur.com/ZZMGnNK.png

Comment: It's not a good idea to format it if you have information that you want to retrieve. It will make data recovery even harder.  It seems that this drive doesn't have a letter assigned to it.  According to the Disk Management screenshot you posted the letter E: is assigned to Disk 1 and the 465 GB one is listed as Disk 2.  Try to assign a letter. If that doesn't help please clarify if the drive is formatted in NTFS and if it was working properly before. You can also try to connect it directly via SATA to rule out possible issue with the SATA to USB bridge.